# Is it possible to detect if a site is using a version control system

Tags: git, svn, version-control, mercurial, web-scraping

Guessing this is most likely not possible, at least by any easy or legal means, but I'm curious if maybe there is some small thing left behind in the public domain by a version control system that would be possible to detect.

Even if its not possible to detect every type of version control, maybe there's a way to see one. Or maybe just a way to see that version control in general is being used, but not specifically which brand.

For instance, if a site is using git, maybe there is a certain hash added to the end of a file that is available on the server and only git uses that structure. Or maybe there is a way to detect that a file has been recently changed and mercurial performed a specific change to the line endings.

Looking for outside of the box answers here

Comment: Just curious, why would you want to know that and how does this information help?

Comment: It's just a theoretical question at the moment, but I'd like to be able to know which version control systems are being used and by which large websites, so that I have hard statistics when deciding which one I will use.

Comment: I would be a bit afraid of such statistics. You will get only data about sites which exposed this information to site user. And sometimes this may correlate with qualities, which you don't want to learn from.

Comment: absolutely agree, that's why checking for the existence of a .git directory is not very helpful. Would be more interested in something involving line endings, file hashes, or something more subtle that isn't a sign of poor architecture, but rather just a convention used by the vcs

Answer (score 3):

There is no reliable way to find that out, but sometimes there traces left in projects. Most common thing is the configuration of the version control system
Git creates a folder called .git, in subversion it's called .svn.
You can try to access them on a website:

Try something like `http://website.com/.git` and `http://website.com/.svn` and so on.
If that folder exists, they are most likely using this VCS.
Mind you, if it does not exist, this does not mean they are not using this VCS. Many servers will be configured to hide these folders from visitors.

Good luck.

Comment: All web servers must be configured to hide `.svn` and `.git` directories for security reasons, IMHO.

Comment: They should, yes. That doesn't mean they are though. My Apache on Debian or Ubuntu does not hide them by default and I am sure most not-so-professional admins don't put in the effort to fix that.

Comment: @MrTweek - only for small startups, not in Big Corprations: they don't like stupid morons

Comment: @Lazy Badger: In a perfect world, yes. I work in this industry and I've seen horrible things ;)

Answer (score 1):

Look at the source code for comments that the developers may have left in. You'd be surprised what teams will leave in there source code comments. While you will not be able to see the server language comments, perhaps the team left a ton of html comments on the site. Some might point the way to the answer you are looking for. Probably nothing like `<!--Git is so cool. I love that we use it on this project-->`  but maybe something that talks about what they are using. This is no guarantee, but if you read through all of the source you can see you just might find your answer.

Answer (score 1):

It will be faster to google or ask.  Since you're talking about big companies just google, check quora, or check the skills listed on their job postings.  For example:

- http://www.quora.com/What-version-control-system-does-Google-use-and-why
- https://code.facebook.com/posts/218678814984400/scaling-mercurial-at-facebook/

The funny thing, though, is that what they *are* using is very rarely what they want to be using and would pick now, so it's not terribly useful data.  Google still officially uses Perforce, but everyone there wishes they were on a modern DVCS.